# Как сделать переход на следующий блок только после окончания слайдера?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, css3

Есть страница с вертикальным слайдером сверху и последующими блоками после него. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать плавный переход на следующий блок ( #block )  после прокрутки последнего изображения в слайдере. Притом #block должен заполнить собой весь экран. Также иногда при перелистывании картинок происходит прокрутка сайта, как устранить этот багос?
P.S.  Используется swiperjs. И самый несущественный вопрос: при перелистывании картинок можно ли между ними добавить задержку и гифку, типа как шипение на телевизоре?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: "vertical",
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="slider">

  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/123/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/124/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/77/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/32/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/53/1000/700" alt=""></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/66/1000/700" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="block" class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Пример](https://codepen.io/kostyabushuev/pen/ZEEWpeM)

У свайпера есть [различные события](https://swiperjs.com/api/#events), на которые можно подписаться. Одно из таких событий называется **slideChange**. Собственно с ним пример и показан выше.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  direction: "vertical",
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    invert: false,
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
  on: {
    slideChange () {
      const countAllSlides = swiper.slides.length
      const swiperIndex = swiper.realIndex

      if (countAllSlides - 1 === swiperIndex) {
         // do scroll 
      }
    }
  }
});

function getCountAllSlides (swiper) {
  return swiper.slides.length
}

function getRealIndex () {
  return swiper.realIndex
}
```

По поводу гифки. Скорее всего возможно через теже события, только использовать уже надо событие начала и окончания перелистывания. И как то между ними вставлять свою гифку.

Comment: Добавил код `document.getElementById("block").scrollIntoView({
           behavior: "smooth",
         });` Однако столнулся с такой проблемой, как только последний слайд становится активным он сразу пролистывается вниз до #block.

Comment: Разве не этот эффект ожидался?

Comment: Нет, не совсем. Переход на #block должен осуществляться при очередном скролле будучи на последнем слайде. Попробовал сделать следющим образом, но работает не совсем корректно (скролл идет очень медленно и после достижения нужной точки не останавливается): `slideChange() {

            document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                document.getElementById("simple-operation").scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: "smooth",
                });
            });

        }`